# Php File viewer

Tags: php, html

I have a system I am developing to handle documents. Now everything process wise is working fine. The only thing I cannot seem to get is the file browser.

Whenever someone submits a document a folder is created with their name and the documents placed inside. I have a bit of code to view the folders but there is no way to add a button so the user can go back to the system.

see my code below:

```
<?php
$dir = opendir('SubmittedDocs/'); 
echo '<ul>';
while ($read = readdir($dir)) 
{

if ($read!='.' && $read!='..') 
{ 
echo '<li><a href="SubmittedDocs/'.$read.'">'.$read.'</a></li>'; 
}

}

echo '</ul>';

closedir($dir); 
?>
```

Comment: Can you not use `../` to read the previous directory? (Be careful of exploits such as `/var/www/website.com/../../../var/`

Comment: What do you mean with "the user can go back to the system"?

Comment: @PierreFrançois  there i no back button to go out of the file browser. Yes im aware you can use the back arrow on the address bar but i need something to make it easier for my users.

Comment: well then you can create a button or hyperlink using HTML? Your code is already creating some HTML, you just need to create some more. Hard to see what the issue is?

Comment: @ADyson  once the user clicks a folder name it opens a file browser much like a website that has nothing on it if you understand what i mean.  There is no way for me to influence it. Check this link that is what it looks like : https://img.raymond.cc/images/download-directory-listings.png

Comment: @ADyson clicking parent directory will take them back to the list of folders but it remains in the file browser. It doesnt go back to the actual layout of the system.

Comment: @Str1fe why you don't try something made up? https://google.com/search?q=php+filemanager If you want to do it yourself, first read some tutorials. (To avoid standard mistakes)

Comment: @bato3 i looked around quite abit and found a few that looked amazing but they dont let the user view/download the files.

Comment: first (for `php server file browser` query): https://tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php

Comment: @Str1fe So add a link which takes them back the main site. Why can't you do that?

Comment: @ADyson sir try the code and you will understand.

Comment: Your code in the question above lists the files in a folder, right? So just add a button just below (or above) it which links back to your main site. I fail to see why you can't add a button to your code above. If you're relying on the default built-in HTML directory listing provided by the webserver, don't. Write your own, problem solved.

Comment: @ADyson thats the issue i was having sir. I was struggling to get it right. But its alright. Bato3 sorted me out.